# How to store a process in rust

Tags: process, rust

I'd like to store a std::io::process::Process inside a struct in rust. However, the program goes defunct as soon as I pass the Process instance to the struct. Why is that? Code:

```
use std::io::process::{Command, Process};
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct DzenInst {
    process: Rc<RefCell<Process>>
    //stdin: std::io::pipe::PipeStream
}

impl DzenInst {
    // Write a string to the stdin of dzen
    fn write(&mut self, s : String) {
        let mut stdin = self.process.borrow_mut().stdin.take().unwrap();
        println!("Writing to dzen inst");
        match stdin.write_str((s + "\n").as_slice()) {
            Err(why) => panic!("couldn't write to dzen stdin: {}", why.desc),
            Ok(_) => println!("Wrote string to dzen"),
        };
    }
}

fn CreateDzen() -> DzenInst {
    DzenInst {process: Rc::new(RefCell::new(
                match Command::new("dzen2").spawn() {
                    Err(why) => panic!("couldn't spawn dzen: {}", why.desc),
                    Ok(process) => process,
                }))}
}

fn main() {
    let mut d1 = CreateDzen();
    d1.write("Test".to_string());

    std::io::timer::sleep(std::time::duration::Duration::seconds(1));    
}
```

If I write to the process stdin immediately inside CreateDzen, then it works just fine (i.e. the program does not go defunct). I'm assuming that copying the Process instance is causing its destructor to be invoked, which closes the process. Any ideas how to store the Process instance without causing the process to go defunct?

Comment: What exactly is the output? It seems right to me given your exact code but with `dzen2` changed to `cat` because I don’t have dzen2 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Rust code is fine. The problem here is `dzen2`. You need to add the `-p` flag to make `dzen2` persist `EOF` (which is in the [dzen2 README](https://github.com/robm/dzen)).

Instead of

```
match Command::new("dzen2").spawn() {
```

Use

```
match Command::new("dzen2").arg("-p").spawn() {
```

Comment: Ah yes, true. Actually, it would be better not to close the stdin to begin with, which I achieved by not using take() on the Option<PipeStream>.